# Save property type int google datastore

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore

How can I define the property type, when I save a record into Google Datastore with PHP?

> version should be type: Integer
>
> color should be type: String
>
> description should be type: Text (I want to save long text there)
>
> created should be type: Date and time
>
> and cardatas should be type Array or Text,

what is the best here for JSON datas?: Array or Text

```
 $datastore = new DatastoreClient();
    $key = 'protCarDatas';
    $time = date(DATE_RFC3339);
    $savedata = $datastore->entity(
        $key,
           [
             'version' => $version,
             'color' => $color,
             'description' => $desc,
             'created' => $time,
             'cardatas' => $fullCardDataJsonString
           ],
           ['excludeFromIndexes' => ['cardatas']]
    );

    $datastore->insert($savedata);
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

The types that Datastore supports are the following ([from the Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#entities,-properties,-and-keys)):

- Integers
- Floating-point numbers
- Strings
- Dates
- Binary data

So I would cast the variables to:

> version: Integer
>
> color: String
>
> description: String
>
> created: Date
>
> cardatas: String

Comment: I can't find a sample, how to set a variable to Integer or String, ...

Comment: You  create the datastore entry with the variables already casted and that's it. I suggest reading the [Storing data section](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial#datastore-datastore-add-entity-php).